# Are there any thematic vocabulary resources with IPA notation?

Tags: vocabulary, resources

I'm looking to extend my vocabulary with Anki, so I'm on the hunt for vocabulary lists. I'm looking for something that is:

- Thematically grouped (so context reduces ambiguity of meaning, e.g. tempo can mean time or weather)
- Includes [IPA notation](https://www.ipachart.com/) (I find it easier to remember and use words if I'm sure of the syllable stress and pronunciation. This also means that I don't have to run to the dictionary to double-check every other word)
- Available in eBook/electronic format (to make it easier to import into Anki without manually typing out 5000+ words)

I found some via Amazon that ticked these three boxes, published by T&P, however they were riddled with mistakes. Does anyone know of a good quality resource that fulfills the above criteria?

Comment: you're probably not finding anything with IPA notation, my suggestion is to learn italian spelling as it's regular although a bit convoluted (less than English), the stresses can be found by looking up the words in any dictionary (the accents indicate them). That may make your search more easy.

Comment: Yep, Italian spelling is mostly regular, but there are enough ambiguities (syllable stress, voiced vs. unvoiced z, etc) to make running to a dictionary every few minutes a real hassle (believe me, I've tried). Thanks anyway though!

Comment: Would a dictionary from German to Italian with all the characteristics you mentioned work as well?